# canvas error for using .toDataUrl()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I am software developer and facing to much trouble of  save canvas
image in server for IE7 and 8 version .Its working in all browser but
not working in above broser please help me .
in this i am stuck in .toDataurl 
i am using code for this .
please provide me any solution or same code with demo .I am facing to much trouble .
thanks in advance .

Comment: I don't think IE7 and IE8 support HTML5 Canvas at all, are you using a library to simulate canvas, such as [excanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/)?  If so, see [this excanvas issue](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=41&q=toDataURL).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created an application in which I had to use toDataURL() but I was not able to find any way to do this in IE7/8. My application was an online image editor in which user was able to save the canvas contents. I believe there is not way we can use this method in IE7/8.